# How to tell if scalar plane equations are perpendicular to one another?

Tags: calculus, vectors

Just by looking at their equations, how can one tell that the following equations intersect at 90º? In other words, how can you tell that they're perpendicular to each other?

Plane 1: 2x − y + 4z + 5 = 0

Plane 2: 3x − 2y − 2z − 7 = 0

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think we all know what you mean, but your terminology is inaccurate. The equations don't intersect (meaningless); rather, the sets they describe (affine linear spaces in this case) might.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two planes are perpendicular iff their corresponding normal vectors are perpendicular. So we just need to look at the coefficients of each variable, compute a dot product, and check that it equals zero. Indeed:
$$
\langle 2, -1, 4 \rangle \cdot \langle 3, -2, -2 \rangle
= 6 + 2 - 8 = 0
$$

Comment: does the last part of each equation (the 5 and -7; also known as D in Ax+By+Cz+d=0) affect the the orientation? Like if I had to construct another plane that's perpendicular to Plane 1, I just need to ensure that the normal vector's dot product=0 and choose any value for D?

Comment: No, it does not affect the orientation. Modifying the $D$ is tantamount to translating the plane in space to get a second plane parallel to the first.